# Cosa significa "perdere il numero" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto quanto segue. Si tratta di parte di un dialogo tra un prete e una vecchia:

> – Dicevo, – precisò ad occhi obliqui, – che io non mi sono mai fatta vedere qui prima d’oggi… 
>         – Beh, l’inverno è all’uscio, e c’è un mucchio di cose da fare: e per voi peggio ancora, suppongo… Chi vi dice di venire in parrocchia? L’importante è non **perdere il numero**. Può sempre venir buono, ecco tutto. 
>         – E io non l’ho perso, – disse lei dopo un po’ sorridendo, come se usare le mie stesse parole fosse bere al mio stesso bicchiere.

Non capisco cosa significa "perdere il numero" in questo contesto. Ho cercato alla voce "numero" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato o non ho saputo trovare nulla al riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato, ***non perdere il numero*** significa essere sempre in grado di trovare la Chiesa in caso di bisogno anche se, come dice la vecchia, non si era mai fatta vedere prima d'oggi.

Numero si può riferire sia al telefono che all'indirizzo, ma in senso figurato significa avere un riferimento fisico ma anche spirituale dove andare a chiedere aiuto in caso di bisogno.

Comment: Scusa, ma il significato che hai spiegato sarebbe quello di "**non** perdere il numero"?

Comment: Sì, scusa mi sono perso la negazione...

Comment: Ma, indipendentemente dalla negazione, il significato è comunque quello di (non) perdere il **riferimento** in caso di bisogno